# SAML2.0 Assertion decrypt

Tags: java, saml-2.0

I'm trying to integrate an Java Web App with an deploied IdP at my school. The IdP is already configured, I make the request and everything is fine, except one. I can't decrypt the IdP response.

[Here you can find the response that I receive after a login](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3902816/resposta_idp_ua.xml)

I have a public_key.crt and a private_key.pem.
I already have decrypted the symetric key inside the IdP response, that was encrypted with my public_key.crt. After that I get a 256 bytes array, wich I think is an AES-256 passphrase, but the IdP Response only talks about an AES-128-CBC. Nevertheless I try to create an Java AES object to decrypt the SAML Assertion, but I always get the error: Invalid AES key length: 256 bytes

Here is the code:

```
    PrivateKey privKey = ...; // PrivateKey constructed with my private_key.pem file
    System.out.println(privKey); // To show private_key.pem info

    // you can find these two strings on IdP Response, from link above 
    String encAssertion = "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";
    String encryptedKey = "qJNLI5UNAVSVwRCI8EHSa5GuhFAxPi9VZleCCrriLHSXWHf79RDG6ocU7slHZaf8zvIc2su41iJsZeb3xXOsg73xbJ2vLOWW5GQCRh97OxFmbd2M0UkYMM57g2YmDlPjTo7L75GrX2LmmL1ko47QmCb60b0um2m6RGNdj32QUIGArUM4TUdamSi0a8+bThe565OUkS25OfrT02z1er1m+VprUa5SPwqLXRqmg9dknCX8pIi5vrD02bRrKP5b+a6FTA77ocOFtYgzPQWPYfAU5jFledHRJA3phwsm7yOFvyjOeWtOVCAKmoYALJ+5rdxnkMGr/SGaI3jjNup7WQJxtw==";

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    byte[] decrypt = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedKey));

    System.out.println("Decrypted Key length: " + decrypt.length); // Decrypted Key length: 256
    System.out.println(new String(decrypt, "UTF-8")); // Some stupid chars

    SecretKey skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decrypt, "AES");

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    // cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    // cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, (Key) skeySpec);
    byte[] decryptedAssertion = cipher.doFinal(encAssertion.getBytes());
```

The error occurs on the last line.
Invalid AES key length: 256 bytes

Comment: Well, it seems like that it is really not a 256 bit keylength AES. Are you sure about all the bitlength, cypher algorithm and cypher modes you mention above? Usually protocols allow negotiation phase where these parameters are discussed. AES has different block sizes and different key sizes too. It's scary to see 2that you hard-code these choices into your code. Can you use some higher level crypto library for your needs?

Comment: I don't have sure about nothing :( but the byte array decrypt have 256 length, but in the IdP Response it says AES-128.
The code is only for tests purposes :)